# Eclipse 2022-03 : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/tm4e/ui/utils/ContentTypeHelper Error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently facing error in eclipse while opening `yaml` as well as `xml` files.

Error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/tm4e/ui/utils/ContentTypeHelper`.

I installed `Eclipse Docker Tooling 5.6.0.20220382138` extension for Dockerfile support via eclipse marketplace.

After installation, I have started seeing above error.  So I uninstalled above plugin to see if that will be of any help but still even after uninstallation, error didn't disappear.

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72043028/spring-plugin-in-eclipse-cannot-open-pom-xml)  & installed extension but it is of no help.

Platform : MacOS

Eclipse : 2022-03 (4.23.0)

Comment: Does installing TM4E 0.4.5 via the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/0.4.5/`](https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/0.4.5/) fix your issue?

Comment: hi @howlger, let me check & get back to you on this. thanks

Comment: Hi @howlger, it's not working even after updating tm4e with 0.4.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific issue, I end up re-installing eclipse from `eclipse installer` as I tried below mentioned things & it still didn't worked:

1. Installed  `https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/0.4.5/` .
2. Uninstalled above version & installed latest release of `tm4e` but no success.
3. Uninstalled `tm4e` completely which started giving me issues where I was unable to save any changes in java class files. Workspace got freeze after this.